# source tree git repo stop tracking a file that doesn't exist

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I just was working on a branch, and when I went to make a commit a file appeared to be tracked that I seemed to have created unintentionally as some stage.

The problem is that this file doesn't exist anymore and I cant stop tracking something that doesn't exist

```
fatal: pathspec 'app/HttpControllers/Admin/Logic.php' did not match any files'
```

I have no idea how this happened, but how can I get rid of it because i can't merge the branch as it says I still have a file in my working directory.

Just a note, I can't stage this file because it doesn't exist. So I am out of idea's.

Answer (score 0):

> I cant stop tracking something that doesn't exist

It may not exist on the disk anymore, but it could still be referenced in the index. Check the output of [`git ls-files`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files).

If you see it, you can remove it from the index:

```
git rm --cached -- app/HttpControllers/Admin/Logic.php
```